# what values does the keras' metrics return? a scalar or a tensor ？

Tags: python, keras

I am writing code about the custom loss function and custom metrics function in Keras. Now it is wrong with the code.

I don't know what values should these custom functions return, a scalar or a tensor which size is 'batch_size'? I tried all of them, surprisingly they all work while the results are different.

So I want to know which of them is right. What is the computing mechanism of 'loss' and 'metrics' when it completes a epoch in training?

The shapes of `y_true` and `y_predict` are (batch_size,1)

### def loss_scalar(y_true,y_pred):

```
main_loss=K.sum(K.reshape((1+0.2*(K.abs((5-y_true)-5/2)))*K.square(y_true-y_pred),shape=(-1,)))
```

### def loss_tensor(y_true,y_pred):

```
main_loss=(K.reshape((1+0.2*(K.abs((5-y_true)-5/2)))*K.square(y_true-y_pred),shape=(-1,))
```

### def mae_tensor(y_true,y_pred):

```
return  (K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred),axis=-1))
```

### def mae_scalar(y_true,y_pred):

```
return  K.sum(K.mean(K.abs(y_true-y_pred),axis=-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras Metrics return:
**Single tensor value representing the mean of the output array across all datapoints.** according to the [doc](https://keras.io/metrics/)